# Second-order arithmetic subsystems

Tags: set-theory, second-order-logic, reverse-math

I've been surfing the internet, and have found some subsystems or additional axioms of second-order arithmetic whose definitions I could not find. Does anyone know what the following axioms/subsystems are?

1. $\beta$-model reflection
2. Lightface comprehension (e.g. lightface $\Pi^1_2$-comprehension)
3. CR (e.g. $\Delta^1_1$-CR, I do not know what CR stands for)
4. Bar recursion (the Wikipedia article for it seems unrelated and confusing)

Comment: The introduction here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01342v3.pdf defines Lightface comprehension.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Binary198 A common and pretty comprehensive reference for this is S. G. Simpson's *Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic*

Comment: A $\beta$-model is a model $M$ of a subsystem of $Z_2$ such that for some ordering $\prec$ on $\omega$, $M\vDash``\prec\textrm{ is well-ordered}"$ iff $\prec$ actually is well-ordered. Equivalently $M\prec_{\Pi_1^1}\mathcal P(\omega)$, where $\Pi_1^1$ is from the analytical hierarchy

Comment: I read some of "Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic". I understand what a $\beta$-model is, but not what is meant by $\beta$-model reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\beta$-model reflection for $\Pi^1_k$ formulas is roughly "for any true $\Pi^1_k$ formula there exists a (countably coded) $\beta$-model in which it holds", some sources are theorem 2.5 of Rathjen's "Proof Theory of Reflection" (appearing for $\Pi^1_{n+1}$ formulas, although not mentioned by name) or section VII.7 of Simpson's *Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic*.

As mentioned by JMP in the comments, lightface $\Pi^1_1$-comprehension is $\Pi^1_1$-comprehension restricted to formulae with no set variable parameters.  I would expect that lightface $\Pi^1_2$-comprehension is the system analyzed in Rathjen's "[An Ordinal Analysis of parameter free $\Pi^1_2$-Comprehension](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/pime.pdf)", but "lightface" does not appear to be explicitly mentioned there. Some other mixtures of lightface and boldface comprehension have been considered, e.g. "$\Pi^1_2(\Pi^1_3)\mathrm{-CA}_0$" as appearing in Welch's "[Weak systems of determinacy and arithmetical quasi-inductive definitions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4412)" (2009, p.3), which is comprehension for $\Pi^1_2$ formulae which are only allowed set parameters that are $\Pi^1_3$-set-parameter-free-definable.

$\Delta^1_n\textrm{-}\mathbf{CR}$ is the "$\Delta^1_n$ comprehension rule", which implements $\Delta^1_n$-comprehension as a rule of inference instead of an axiom, it is defined on p.14 of Rathjen's "[Proof Theory: From arithmetic to set theory](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/Sepp-chiemsee.pdf)" (2014).

I am not very familiar with bar induction, but the definition of the bar recursion rule seems to appear in Chapter VI of *The Handbook of Proof Theory* (1998), Avigad and Feferman's "Gödel's Functional ("Dialectica") Interpretation", on page 32 of [this](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Efeferman/papers/dialectica.pdf) draft version, with the following definition. Lemma 6.4.1 of this source is that over a certain higher-type extension of Gödel's [System $T$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectica_interpretation), assuming bar recursion, you can prove bar induction.

[image: Definition of bar recursion from The Handbook of Proof Theory]

Comment: Thanks! I got SOSOA recently, but I haven't read much of it yet.